# tablas del sistema oracle express

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

acabo de instalarme el oracle 11 g express, ejecuto el sql developer.

He creado una base de datos llamada: noviembre, en el momento de expandir las tablas me parecen unas tablas que al parecer son del sistema, quisiera saber como hago para que no me aparezcan... solo necesito las que voy  crear.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

SQL Developer ya funciona como lo deseas. O sea que, por defecto, solo te muestra las tablas que pertenecen al usuario conectado.

Pero parece que te has conectado usando el usuario `system`, que es dueño de varias tablas sistema, por eso las ves.

Si no quieres ver las tablas sistema, entonces no te conectes usando el usuario `system`.  Mas bien, crea un usuario nuevo, y conéctate usando ese usuario. De esta manera solo verás las tablas que creas bajo ese nuevo usuario.